# Scaling a matrix to make its eigenvalues fall within a certain interval

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose I have a diagonalizable matrix $M$ which has all its eigenvalues between $a$ and $b$. Is it possible to scale $M$ to $M_S$ such that all the eigenvalues of $M_s$ lie in the interval $[-1,1]$?

One method I came across:
Scale such that
$$ 
M_s=\frac{M-(b+a)/2}{(b-a)/2}.
$$
But, this is not working. Does anyone know anything better?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "scaling"?

Comment: Any kind of transformation. I said scaling because the length and the position of eigenvalue interval is changed.

Comment: Finding such a transformation is equivalent to finding a function that maps $[a,b]$ into $[-1,1]$. You seem to be well-aware of this fact. If so, I am confused how you know about diagonalizable matrices but don't know how to map one interval into another

Comment: I want to transform the matrix such that I get the eigenvalues in the required interval. It is not just simple mapping of the interval.

Comment: It could be helpful if you added a few words about the origin of your matrix $M$. Also, in what sense is your original transformation failing? What is it that you hope to achieve by transforming your matrix?

Comment: There are methods to find eigenvalues of a matrix using Chebychev polynomials. Now since Chebyshev polynomials are defined only for x in the range -1 and +1, these methods require the eigenvalues to be between -1 and +1.

Comment: Transformation via Chebychev polynomials is frequently done when you want to isolate a portion of the spectrum. It is problematic at best, unless you have a nice separation between the eigenvalues that you want and those you want to discard. Frequently, an excessively high degree is required making it extremely costly to apply the Lanczos algorithm. 
Good luck :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that the following transformation works,
$$Ms=\frac{M−((b+a)/2) I}{(b−a)/2}$$ where I is a Identity matrix.
$M_s$ also has the same eigenvectors as the original matrix $M$.

Answer (score 3):

So the added constraint to your problem is that eigenvalues $a$ and $b$ must be mapped to $-1$ and $1$.
One possible solution is what follows.

If T is the diagonalizing matrix of M, then

$M=TDT^{-1}$, where $D=\begin{bmatrix}
a&0&0&\dots\\
0&b&0&\dots\\
0&0&c&\dots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
\end{bmatrix}
$

The rescaling transformation for a diagonal D matrix that maps eigenvalues $a$ and $b$ to $-1$ and $1$ would be $R_D$ such that the following holds (let's call $D_1$ the output of such a rescaling):

$D_1 = R_DD$, where $R_D = \begin{bmatrix}
-1/a&0&0&\dots\\
0&1/b&0&\dots\\
0&0&1&\dots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
\end{bmatrix}$

Now let's call $M_1$ the rescaling of M such that eigenvalues $a$ and $b$ are mapped to $-1$ and $1$. It must be:

$M_1 = TD_1T^{-1} = TR_DDT^{-1} = TR_DT^{-1}TDT^{-1} = R_MM$.

So the rescaling transformation you are looking for is given by the multiplication on the left by the matrix:

$R_M = TR_DT^{-1}$

Comment: Yeah this works. But, the reason I wanted to do the transformation was to find eigenvalues. It is easier to find eigenvalues when they are in the range $[-1,1]$. The transformation you proposed require eigenvalues of the original matrix beforehand. So, I can't use your method. But, yeah it is technically correct. Actually your previous answer helped me to come up with a proper method. I'll upvote that when I cross 15 points.

Answer (score 1):

$M_S=sign(a+b)/max(|a|, |b|) M$

Comment: What does sign mean?

Comment: plus or minus. You need to scale all eigenvalues for them to be in $[-1, 1]$. So if $a$ and $b$ are both positive you need to divide $M$ by the maximum between $a$ and $b$. If both are negative you need to divide $M$ by the minimum between $a$ and $b$ that in these case is $-max(|a|, |b|)$. If $a>0$ and $b<0$ you need to divide $M$ by $max(a, |b|)$ and then multiply by $1$ or $-1$ if $max(a, |b|)=a$ or $max(a, |b|)=-b$ respectively. If $a<0$ and $b>0$ you need to divide $M$ by $max(|a|, b)$ and then multiply by $1$ or $-1$ if $max(|a|, b)=b$ or $max(|a|, b)=-a$ respectively. So my formula.

Comment: Hey, it works in the sense that the eigenvalues are between 1 and -1. But, I need eigenvalue corresponding to $a$ to be mapped to $-1$ and $b$ to $1$.

Comment: but that's exactly what you asked. Maybe you need to explain better which kind of problem you are trying to solve. Anyway I will answer to the new problem with the added contraint, but it is starting to be a nonsense.